# UIImage setImage lag in UItableView

Tags: uitableview, uiscrollview, uiimage, reusability

I have a UITableView,and I put a UIScrollView in each custom UITableViewCell.Just like aribnb does.I have some UIImage to show some images from internet,everything does right.
    But when I downloaded the images and want to show out them again in tableViewCell,I use the following codes,I found it lag to show out the new and right image to change the old and reuse image,almost 2 or 3 seconds.

here is my tableviewcell delegate

```
static NSString *ReusedIdentifier = @"mainDailyTableViewCell";
ILDailyTableViewCell *cell = (ILDailyTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ReusedIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[ILDailyTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:ReusedIdentifier
                                              viewType:VIEWTYPE_DETAIL];
    [cell.itemScrollView setItemDelegate:self];
}
if (indexPath.row < [_contentList count])
{
    ILDailyItemInfo *preRowDailayItem = [_contentList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSMutableArray *cellItemList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (id item in preRowDailayItem.dealList)
        [cellItemList addObject:item];
    if ([cellItemList count] == 0)
        cellItemList = nil;
    [cell setCellItems:cellItemList];
}
else
    [cell setCellItems:nil];
return cell;
```

and here is my pre item view set image method

-(void)showOutMainImageInfo:(ILDailyItemInfo *)itemInfo
{

```
UIImage *showImage = itemInfo.image;

__block ILDailyItemView *weakSelf = self;
    if (showImage == nil)
    {
        [[SDWebImageManager sharedManager] downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl] options:SDWebImageRetryFailed progress:nil completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {
            itemInfo.image = image;
            [_dailyItemImageView showWithMain:[ILResizeImage resizeImage:image withRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, weakSelf.itemMainImageView.frame.size.width, weakSelf.itemMainImageView.frame.size.height)]
                                  bottomImage:[[ILResizeImage resizeImage:image withRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, weakSelf.bottomImageView.frame.size.width, weakSelf.bottomImageView.frame.size.height)] applyExtraLightEffect]];
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        [_dailyItemImageView showWithMain:[ILResizeImage resizeImage:showImage withRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, weakSelf.itemMainImageView.frame.size.width, weakSelf.itemMainImageView.frame.size.height)]
                              bottomImage:[[ILResizeImage resizeImage:showImage withRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, weakSelf.bottomImageView.frame.size.width, weakSelf.bottomImageView.frame.size.height)] applyExtraLightEffect]];
    }
```

}

and, here is my daily item image view draw method

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

```
if (_mainImage)
{
    [_mainImage drawInRect:_mainImageFrame];
}
if (_bottomImage)
{
    [_bottomImage drawInRect:_bottomImageFrame];
}
```

}

Comment: Try to use SDWebImage to deal with image loading with async. https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/

Comment: That's right,I am using SDWebImage to download image,but I use my self draw method to handle the cached image.Perhaps my custom cell has lots of items.Such as a main image,a blur image at bottom,two labels,two buttons,and a translucent shade image.

Comment: It will better if you post more code so we can more easy to find out the issue.

Comment: May be it has too much levels,I can just post some of it.